# I want to create javadoc of current and other project in single gradle file

Tags: gradle, javadoc

I  need the gradle task to create javadoc analogous to this ant script:

```
<target name="javadoc" depends="deployable" description="packaging java doc">

    <javadoc destdir="${javaDocDir}" author="true"
        stylesheetfile="./java_doc.css"
        use="true" source="1.8" version="true"private="true">
        <packageset dir="${lk-kor-source.dir}" defaultexcludes="yes">
            <include name="com/capsilon/katalyst/sso/datatypes" />
            <include name="com/capsilon/katalyst/business/objects" />
            <include name="com/capsilon/katalyst/business/objects/condition"/>
            <include name="com/capsilon/katalyst/business/datatypes" />
            <include name="com/capsilon/katalyst/business/datatypes/conditions" />
            <include name="com/capsilon/katalyst/business/objects/collection" />
            <include name="com/capsilon/katalyst/datatype" />
            <include name="com/capsilon/katalyst/business/datatypes/delivery" />
            <include name="com/capsilon/katalyst/business/objects/esign" />
            <include name="com/capsilon/katalyst/business/objects/fee" />
            <include name="com/capsilon/katalyst/annotations" />
        </packageset>
        <packageset dir="${source.dir}" defaultexcludes="yes">
            <include name="com/capsilon/katalyst/business/objects" />
            <include name="com/capsilon/katalyst/business/datatypes" />
            <include name="com/capsilon/katalyst/business/datatypes/request" />
            <include name="com/capsilon/katalyst/services/exception" />
            <include name="com/capsilon/katalyst/services" />
        </packageset>
        <bottom>
            <![CDATA[<i>Copyright &#169; 2016 Capsilon Corp. All Rights Reserved.</i>]]></bottom>
    </javadoc>
```

please also specify how to declare classpath